# PHP read directories in cyrillic

Tags: php, encoding, directory, cyrillic

I'm using the glob function to get all directories like this for example:

```
$dirs = array_filter(glob('documents/*'), 'is_dir');
```

However if the directory name is in cyrillic this function won't work. I assume it's an encoding issue. Is there any other function or a way to do the same with directories with cyrillic names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the folowing code:

```
$dirs = glob('documents/*', GLOB_NOESCAPE | GLOB_ERR | GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

This will print errors and only directories.